# add raw html post to hugo not show up

Tags: hugo

I am using [Academic](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/) theme. I wish to put some raw html page as post. but sounds like it doesn't show correctly on my post pages. my html page has title there!

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example html post</title>
</head>
....
```

How show I change my theme to show my raw html posts?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that Hugo (and any Markdown transpiler) will transpile any HTML tags in your markdown file to actual HTML tags in the HTML document.

Since code highlighting is supported in Hugo 0.28 and upwards, you can show your raw HTML code (or any code) just by surrounding your code with `{{< highlight html >}}` and `{{< / highlight >}}`

an example of this would be:

```
{{< highlight html >}}
    <h1> Hello World! </h1>
{{< / highlight >}}
```

or for javascript:

```
{{< highlight js >}}
    let hello = "Hello World!";
{{< / highlight >}}
```

For all the options available refer to [this page](https://gohugo.io/content-management/syntax-highlighting/).